# Deploying Simple Python Script to Google Cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Any ideas on how I can easily deploy a simple Python script that will run for weeks on a Google server? I know I can SSH into a machine and run the commands manually but this seems way too complex for such a simple task.

Comment: Do you think that is too complex??? That is one of the simplest methods to run commands on a remote machine. Google Cloud offers "Cloud Shell". You can launch cloud shell in your browser with a button click and run commands. However, not for weeks. You will need to launch a Compute Engine VM, connect via SSH and then run your command.

Comment: SSHing in is a pain and will be much worse when I have to run 100 of these at the same time. I'm trying this out with docker - so far seems like the right solution

Comment: If it is a simple script you can use Google Functions or App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run 100 scripts on 100 different VM, I understand that SSH is boring and not efficient.

The best solution to run simple stuff at scale is to use container and container orchestrator.

Package your script to run it at container start (in the entrypoint) and deploy it on Kubernetes (GKE on Google Cloud). Set the number of replicas that you want, the quantity of CPU that you want on each Pod (set on containers, can be only 1), and enjoy!

It's not less complex than a simple SSH, but it's scalable, elastic and production ready.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of right now it to use "Ansible". Write an Ansible playbook that will have all the tasks that you need to perform on multiple server. And create an Inventory file with all the server details in it.

At max you require two file that too with minimal scripting using YAML.

You can create a task list.

tasks.yaml

```
---
- name: run python
  hosts: all
  remote_user: clouduser
  tasks:
     - name: task1-install pyhton
       yum:
          name: python3-devel
          state: present
     - name: task2-run script
       shell: "##your python run command##"
```

Inventory file will be like. **file can be found in /etc/ansible/hosts

---

```
[all]
192.168.1.5 ansible_user=clouduser ansible_password=hello@123
192.168.1.6 ansible_user=clouduser ansible_password=hello@123
```